# ExtractHL7Attributes NiFi Processor

Tags: apache, encoding, apache-nifi, processor

Has anyone used this NiFi processor successfully with HL7 messages? I am getting the following error:

ca.uhn.hl7v2.parser.EncodingNotSupportedException: Determine encoding for message. The following is the first 50 chars of the message for reference, although this may not be where the issue is.

Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Go to your NiFi installation directory and go into `logs` directory. There you will see `nifi-app.log`. Upload that here.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. That's where I saw the error, it was logged in nifi-app.log. Do you know what the cause of this is? I've checked my HL7 against verifiers but I'm still getting this error.

Comment: What I meant was, post the complete stacktrace from `nifi-app.log`. Sharing bits and pieces won't help much.